Are movie identification questions allowed again?
Movie identification questions were banned about at the end of 2017 on this site. I answered a lot of these questions back then, but after the ban, a lot of my old answers were closed/deleted/not allowed/disappeared (whatever the proper term is for that), and my points decreased as well due to this.
But today I have just noticed that a lot of old identification questions are appearing again, and my old answers and points are also restored. So, what is happening? Are movie identification questions allowed again on this site? Thank you, and Happy Holidays to everyone!

galacticninja, thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with other parts of the site, so I was not aware of those other threads about this topic you pointed me at. Thank you again.

In a word, yes. We've allowed them again and asked a Community Manager to restore the questions that were deleted from the site in the great purge of 2018.

I wonder why there's no post notifying that this "great undeletion" just happened.

Oh, JNat made an answer to an earlier post https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5112/19132

@Mithoron anyone who'd asked a question got a notice.   I got 3 notices.

@userLTK There should be a new meta post - that kind of notice. Preferably pinned as "featured on meta". An answer to the old one will do, I guess, but it's a bit harder to find, isn't it?
